# What defines Fusion-Evaporation Reactions in Nuclear Physics?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, fusion, neutrons

A bit of a general question I know; but I would like to understand a bit more about the topic.

The situation is an alpha beam is incident on an Aluminium-27 target, which ejects a neutron and leaves a Phosphorus-30 isotope, which then decays by beta+ decay.

Apparently this is a fusion-evaporation reaction? But I don't really understand what defines it that way? Is it due to the alpha being added to the aluminium nucleus, making a temporary excited phosphorus-31, which ejects the neutron?

Comment: I was going to link to a question ~8 months ago, but realized it was your question. I guess one could call it a fusion-evaporation reaction. But I have usually heard 'evaporation' of neutrons used for fission to differentiate from the prompt neutrons left as bits of the nucleus disintegrating vs the delayed/evaporation neutrons that 'boil off' neutron rich daughter products. May be subfield specific terminology.

Comment: Ha, probably quite a specific reaction to be fair. Good memory though! I guess my question was mostly what is it that makes this reaction a 'fusion - evaporation' reaction, having never heard the term before. Would an excited Phosphorus-31 constitute particularly neutron rich? Like you say, may be a subfield specific thing, but think this is mostly just plain old nuclear physics reference data work.

Comment: P-31 is the stable isotope of phosphorus, so, no, it isn't neutron rich. Given there are 27Al($\alpha$,p)30Si and 27Al($\alpha$,$\gamma$)31P reactions, it also isn't like there are not other viable paths for the compound nucleus to shed excess energy. So, yeah, I'm not big on the use of 'evaporation' - it is just an ordinary old nuclear reaction.

Comment: Yeh, that was my assessment of it too - it's only from talking with colleagues that the term 'fusion-evaporation reaction' has come about. As you said, none of these are particularly neutron rich or anything. Thanks for letting me know anyway!